# How to update a value type in IMemoryCache without changing the expiration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm storing an `int` in IMemoryCache. When I attempt to update it, the change isn't persisted. I'm guessing it's because I'm using a value type. When I use a dictionary and update an entry within the dictionary it works fine but I only need an int.

I also tried added `ref` to `userCount` but didn't work either.

```
// Startup
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer().AddInMemoryCaching()
}

public void UpdateCounter()
{
    IMemoryCache memCache = httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache)) as IMemoryCache;

    // If entry exists, increment value
    if (cache.TryGetValue("UserCountKey", out int userCount))
    {
        userCount++; // DOESN'T WORK
    }
    // Entry doesn't exist, create with exipre
    else
    {
        cache.Set("UserCountKey", 1, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
    }   
}
```

Comment: You need to set `userCount` back into cache after you increment it.

Comment: @Brad I've done that but calling Set would overwrite the existing expiration value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference type to hold your value and update the field inside that type. This updates the cached value without resetting the expiry timer.

```cs
public class UserCountCache
{
    public int UserCount { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var cachedCount = memCache.Get<UserCountCache?>("UserCountKey");

if (cachedCount != null)
{
    cachedCount.UserCount = 50; // new value
}
```

I know this is a very late answer but I needed to figure this out myself. It may help someone.